# Blade template, html decoding

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a blade template in laravel and some of my variables are showing raw strings with html tags in place, but I want to show the html on the front end obviously.

Here's one I've tested:

```
<p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" >{{html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc)}}</p>
```

Unfortunately, this did not fix the issue. I also tried with `!!` around each end and it seemed to allow some tags but it also showed my curly braces and the exclaimations on the page.

Any help to get this decoded properly?

Comment: `{!! html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc) !!}` or just bypass Blade and do raw PHP, like `<?= $pgroup->group_desc ?>`. Make sure the file is `.blade.php` and not just `.php`, though.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: OK, turned that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{!! html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc) !!}` or just bypass Blade and do raw PHP, like `<?= $pgroup->group_desc ?>`. Make sure the file is `.blade.php` and not just `.php`, though.